# WS_EX_COMPOSITED prevents Paint

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, paint

I'm developing a C# Winforms Application. The GUIs are partly really huge (over 200 controls per form). Until recently I had big problems with flickering. I got the problem under control by using WS_EX_COMPOSITED on the main panel:

```
public class MainPanel : Panel {

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
            get {
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000; // WS_EX_COMPOSITED
                return cp;
            }
        }
...
```

Unfortunately, applying WS_EX_COMPOSITED has some side effects. One issue is, that drawing on controls no longer seems to work. The following code works only, if WS_EX_COMPOSITED is not used:

```
Graphics gr = myControl.CreateGraphics();
gr.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red, 10), 0,0 , 1000, 100);
```

I would prefer still to use WS_EX_COMPOSITED, with the exception of the controls on which I draw.

Comment: Move your code to the `Paint` event.

Comment: The paint-function side effect is just one of many problems. All I want is just to use WS_EX_COMPOSITED excluding some of the child controls.

Comment: keep in mind when using WM_EX_COMPOSITED that child controls will be painted from back to front. Also, use the controls Graphics context, don't create your own, AND be sure to release it when done [as stated by the master... https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171018-00/?p=97245]